# one more "Input string was not in the correct format" c#

Tags: c#, string

I get the above error message when trying to convert a `string` to an `int` in C#. I realize the problem has been discussed many times, but none of the proposed solutions worked for me. I get my string from reading a .csv file using `StreamReader`.

> Printing it using Debug.Log("str") returns "17".

However, all of the below attempts resulted in the same error:

```
        //int value = int.Parse(str); 
        //int value = Int32.Parse(str); 
        //int value = Convert.ToInt32(str.Replace(" ", "")); 
        //Int32 value = Int32.Parse(str); 
        //int value = int.Parse(str.Trim()); 
        //int value = int.Parse(str.ToString().Trim()); 
        //int value = int.Parse(str.ToString().Replace(" ", "").Trim()); 
        //int value = int.Parse(str.Replace(" ", ""));
        //int value = Convert.ToInt32(str); 
        //int value = Convert.ToInt32(str.ToString().Replace(" ", "").Trim()); 
        //decimal value = decimal.Parse(str); 
        //decimal value = Convert.ToDecimal(str);
        //float value = float.Parse(str);
```

> Using `Int32.TryParse(str, out value);` returns 0 and does not help.

Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: You should include the actual *input*, not just the outcome you get. What *is* `str`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: If you are reading a csv you must split line using str.Split(new char[] {'.'}).ToArray();

Comment: Is it truly "17"? There are totally invisible characters

Comment: Technically, `Int32.TryParse` cannot *return* 0, as it returns a bool for success or failure. If it returns false, the out parameter is not valid.

Comment: could you please share your code where you are getting your string from reading a .csv file using StreamReader ?

Comment: You have probably a hidden character in your `str`. try this before trying the cast: `str = new string(str.Where(x => char.IsLetterOrDigit(x)).ToArray());`

Comment: `Int32.TryParse` returns `false` with outer parameter set into its *default value* (`0` in case of `int`)

Comment: why not give this a look http://www.filehelpers.net/ or https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper

Comment: str = new string(str.Where(x => char.IsLetterOrDigit(x)).ToArray()); solved the problem, thank you!!

Comment: Is str "17"?  I.e. does the string include the quotation marks?  If so, you need to remove them.

Comment: What is the value of `str.Length`?

Comment: @mjwills OP just said the code in my comment helped him, so the problem was obviously that the string had some hidden symbols

Comment: Good call, thanks @Pikoh .

Comment: `Debug.Log("str")` cannot possibly return `"17"` since you're logging a string literal!

Answer (score 0):

Not all symbols are *visible*, e.g.:

http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200B/index.htm

http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2063/index.htm

That's why when having eerie errors like this (`int.TryParse(str, out val) == false` and `Console.Write(str);` returns `17`) I suggest *dumping* the actual string:

```
  string str = "1\u20637"; // 17 with invisible separator between 1 and 7

  // dump: hex representation followed by string representation
  string dump = $"{string.Join(" ", str.Select(c => ((int)c).ToString("x4")))} '{str}'"; 

  Console.Write(dump); // or Debug.Log or what ever
```

When having the dump built (please, notice the innocent string representation - `'17'`)

```
  0031 2063 0037 '1⁣7'
```

You can easily detect wrong doer `\u2063` in the code above